# In a Sharepoint Wiki Page Library can I make a custom numbered list or bulleted list format?

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki, wiki-pages

In a Sharepoint Wiki Page Library the bullet and numbered list formats appear to be locked down to one specific, uneditable format.

Is there anyway to change this and create a custom format?
Specifically I would like to chage the numbering from

1. List item 1
2. List item 2

   1. First sub list item
   2. Second sub list item
3. List item 3

to

1. List item 1
2. List item 2

   a. First sub list item

   b. Second sub list item
3. List item 3

I'm using

Office 365 Business v 1804 build 9226.2114

Google chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

If you click on Edit Source, you can add a type to the `<ol>` tag.
e.g. `<ol type="a">` to get lower case letters.

- `type="1"` - numbers (default)
- `type="A"` - uppercase letters
- `type="a"` - lowercase letters
- `type="I"` - uppercase roman numbers
- `type="i"` - lowercase roman numbers

Comment: see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Answer (score 0):

The type of formatting you can do in a web page is limited. A web page (sharepoint or not) is not Microsoft Word or PowerPoint.

You cannot modify the numbered list button default behavior to get your result, the most you can do it find a CSS code that changes the appearance of the standard numbering and apply it to the page where you want this result to happen. I personally do not think the hassle behind it is worth the result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hate to break it to you, but SharePoint Wiki sucks when it comes to formatting. I follow either of the below means to work my way out of Wiki pages formatting

**Method 1:** Perform all the formatting in MS-Word. Copy the content and then paste it in your Wiki page as ***Plain text***. After that use the left/right Indent button to format. I know this is painful, but it gets the job done. Check out the screenshot below employing the same method.

[image]

**Method 2:** Use HTML and tags such as `<ul>`, `<ol>`, etc. This HTML snippet can be inserted using either a Content Editor Webpart or Script Editor webpart.

Hope this helps!